# Get main URL form whole URL string in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have Followings URL :

```
https://www.website.com/b/vIGmD7VS/team-to-do
```

I want only `https://www.website.com`

How can i get?

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is using `parse_url()`. Like:

```
$str = 'https://www.website.com/b/vIGmD7VS/team-to-do';
$urlParts = parse_url($str);
```

This will return as:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => https
    [host] => www.website.com
    [path] => /b/vIGmD7VS/team-to-do
)
```

So just append the values like:

```
$url = $urlParts['scheme'] . "://" . $urlParts['host'];
```

Doc: [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

---

In js, you can do:

```js
var p = document.createElement('a');
p.href = "https://www.website.com/b/vIGmD7VS/team-to-do";

var url = p.protocol + "//" + p.hostname;

console.log(p.protocol);
console.log(p.hostname);
console.log(url);
```

Comment: Is there any function available in javascript to get above main url? I want to pass main URL while I searching.

Comment: @Tejas in nodejs or on front end js?

Comment: In frontend js. For example I have below code: var url = tabs[0].url; chrome.tabs.create({url: "https://www.website.com/b/vIGmD7VS/team-to-do="+url}, function(tab){});

Comment: You can `createElement` for it. Please check updated post @Tejas

Comment: Thank you  so much.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170341/discussion-between-tejas-and-eddie).